# Using volley to make 2 separate remote requests with one method

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Please, what am i doing wrong? I'm using volley to fetch data from Moviedb api. First method call is supposed to fetch popular movies and store them in ArrayListA(popularMoviesList) and second call is supposed to fetch top rated movies and store in another ArrayListB(topRatedMoviesList). But when i call the method and pass their respective urls, ArrayListA contains data for both popular and top rated movies and ArrayListB is empty.

This is the class that has the method

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MovieDataSource {
private final static String MOVIE_ID="id";
private final static String MOVIE_RATING = "vote_average";
private final static String MOVIE_TITLE = "original_title";
private final static String MOVIE_POSTERPATH = "poster_path";
private final static String MOVIE_DESCRIPTION = "overview";
private final static String MOVIE_RELEASEDATE = "release_date";
private final static String API_KEY = "";// paste api key inside the double quote

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getmInstance().getmRequestQueue();


public ArrayList<Movie> movieArrayList(String URL){

    final ArrayList<Movie> listOfMovies = new ArrayList<>();

    String url= URL + API_KEY;

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest= new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    int movieId;
                    double movieRating;
                    String movieTitle, imagePath, movieDescription,movieReleaseDate;

                    Log.i("successful", response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results"); // get json array from the object
                        JSONObject object; // to get objects from result array

                        Movie movie;

                        for(int i=0; i<results.length(); i++) {
                            object = results.getJSONObject(i);// get objects in the array based on their position/index in the array

                            //get values from the objects that will be used to populate instantiated movies
                            movieId = object.getInt(MOVIE_ID);
                            movieRating = object.getDouble(MOVIE_RATING);
                            movieTitle = object.optString(MOVIE_TITLE);
                            imagePath = object.optString(MOVIE_POSTERPATH);
                            movieDescription = object.optString(MOVIE_DESCRIPTION);
                            movieReleaseDate = object.optString(MOVIE_RELEASEDATE);
                            //// for every element in the array( index i), create a new movie
                            movie = new Movie(movieId,movieRating,movieTitle,imagePath,movieDescription, movieReleaseDate);
                            // add each movie created to the arrayList
                            listOfMovies.add(movie);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("error", "onErrorResponse: something went wrong ");

                }
            });

    mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    return  listOfMovies;
}
```

The method is invoked in  MainActivity

```
MovieDataSource movieDataSource = new MovieDataSource();
final ArrayList<Movie>popularMoviesList = movieDataSource.movieArrayList(popularMoviesUrl)
final ArrayList<Movie> topRatedMoviesList = movieDataSource1.movieArrayList(topRatedMovieUrl);
```

The problem is: popularMovieList contains its own expected data and data meant for topRatedMoviesList. Nothing is returned to topRatedMoviesList. What could be responsible for this behavior?

Comment: Can you try printing the response data and verify the logs. I believe you may not be getting any response  for the `topRatedMovieUrl`.
    

Just add `Log.i("movie","My logs "+object.toString());` before  `listOfMovies.add(movie);`

Comment: there are responses for both. I/successful: {"page":1,"total_results":19928,"total_pages":997,"results":[{"vote_count":1171,"id":383498
I/successful: {"page":1,"total_results":7314,"total_pages":366,"results":[{"vote_count":1491,"id":19404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use callbacks (interfaces) instead of using return value.

- Returning a value works with synchronous task, like calculating sum of two numbers when you don't need to put calculation code in seperated thread.
- Returning a value does not work with Asynchronous task like calling rest api or doing long time consuming task. Because as its name **Async** says it will parallelly execute task.

**What your code will do (Is Totally wrong):**

- It will create a list
- Will call a api in separate task ([See AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)), so your code will not wait to let its response come.
- It will return you blank list.
- Now when your response come, it has nothing to do with that.

**Solution :**

If you knew about interfaces, you would have use that. Interfaces are used to invoke some method when your task is done.

**Correct way to implement api in your code will be as below**

```
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_POPULAR = 1;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_TOP_RATED = 2;

    ArrayList<Movie> popularMoviesList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Movie> topRatedMoviesList = new ArrayList<>();

    private void setData() {
        String popularMoviesUrl = "yourUrl";
        String topRatedMovieUrl = "yourUrl";
        MovieDataSource object = new MovieDataSource(); // use only one object
        OnResponseListener<ArrayList<Movie>> listener = new OnResponseListener<ArrayList<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int tag, ArrayList<Movie> object) {
                if (tag == REQUEST_CODE_POPULAR) {
                    popularMoviesList = object;
                    // TODO: 5/27/2018 use this list further
                } else if (tag == REQUEST_CODE_TOP_RATED) {
                    topRatedMoviesList = object;
                    // TODO: 5/27/2018 use this list further
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
//            todo handle error
            }
        };
        object.movieArrayList(popularMoviesUrl, REQUEST_CODE_POPULAR, listener);
        object.movieArrayList(topRatedMovieUrl, REQUEST_CODE_TOP_RATED, listener);
    }
```

And your `MovieDataSource` class.

```
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MovieDataSource {
    private final static String MOVIE_ID = "id";
    private final static String MOVIE_RATING = "vote_average";
    private final static String MOVIE_TITLE = "original_title";
    private final static String MOVIE_POSTERPATH = "poster_path";
    private final static String MOVIE_DESCRIPTION = "overview";
    private final static String MOVIE_RELEASEDATE = "release_date";
    private final static String API_KEY = "";// paste api key inside the double quote
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getmInstance().getmRequestQueue();

    public void movieArrayList(String URL, final int tag, final OnResponseListener<ArrayList<Movie>> listener) {
        final ArrayList<Movie> listOfMovies = new ArrayList<>();
        String url = URL + API_KEY;
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        int movieId;
                        double movieRating;
                        String movieTitle, imagePath, movieDescription, movieReleaseDate;
                        try {
                            JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results"); // get json array from the object
                            JSONObject object; // to get objects from result array
                            Movie movie;
                            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                                object = results.getJSONObject(i);// get objects in the array based on their position/index in the array
                                //get values from the objects that will be used to populate instantiated movies
                                movieId = object.getInt(MOVIE_ID);
                                movieRating = object.getDouble(MOVIE_RATING);
                                movieTitle = object.optString(MOVIE_TITLE);
                                imagePath = object.optString(MOVIE_POSTERPATH);
                                movieDescription = object.optString(MOVIE_DESCRIPTION);
                                movieReleaseDate = object.optString(MOVIE_RELEASEDATE);
                                //// for every element in the array( index i), create a new movie
                                movie = new Movie(movieId, movieRating, movieTitle, imagePath, movieDescription, movieReleaseDate);
                                // add each movie created to the arrayList
                                listOfMovies.add(movie);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        listener.onSuccess(tag, listOfMovies);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        listener.onError(error);
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("error", "onErrorResponse: something went wrong ");
                    }
                });

        mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
      // removed return type, as it was redundant. 
    }


    interface OnResponseListener<T extends List> {
        void onSuccess(int tag, T object);
        void onError(Exception e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working but i don't fully understand the code. Please could you walk me through the method setData()? I'm confused with sequence of events. If i understand correctly, object.movieArrayList(popularMoviesUrl, REQUEST_CODE_POPULAR, listener); does not return the list of the movies. As soon as the listener detects a successful response, data is returned to the Onsuccess method. Therefore, Onsuccess method finishes its execution before object.movieArrayList(popularMoviesUrl, REQUEST_CODE_POPULAR, listener) finishes running/returns any data if applicable?

Comment: I missed removing return type of method, i edited this answer, removed return type, because it was useless.

Comment: Yes you are right, when success or error response is called then we do further things and callback is sent via interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your request runs asynchronously. So, you run 2 requests with same movieDataSource. When both requests completes you fill same movieDataSource.listOfMovies which then returned. Try creating separate MovieDataSource for each request in MainActivity.

```
MovieDataSource movieDataSource1 = new MovieDataSource();
final ArrayList<Movie>popularMoviesList = movieDataSource1.movieArrayList(popularMoviesUrl)
MovieDataSource movieDataSource2 = new MovieDataSource();
final ArrayList<Movie> topRatedMoviesList = movieDataSource2.movieArrayList(topRatedMovieUrl);
```

But to be honest this code looks wrong for me. You return empty array immediately and then fill it when request completes, but how your MainActivity should know if it ready? I'd pass completion callback from MainActivity that could be called with received array as an argument when request completes. Ask me if you need additional help.

Comment: Could you please expatiate more on "You return empty array immidiately and then fill it when request completes". How/why does this happen? I will also appreciate a code improvement example on the callback. You may be right about the empty list. My log.i returns 0 when i try to get count of objects in the arraylist.

Comment: Well, what you shoyld understand is that Volley executes your request in separate task. This means, your onResponse() is not guarantued to be called immidiately. In mist cases it will be calked much later, depending on your internet speed. Or not called at all in case of error.

Comment: So, your movieArrayList() is executed like this: first is "new JsonObjectRequest()", then "mRequestQueue.add()" and finally return. And only much later in time, after return and other code, when internet data actually received, onResponse() are callee by the Volley in separate task. This means your medthod does not modify array when you call this method. It will be modified at some moment in future, or never. But your MainActivity expects some data immidiately after calling movieArrayList().

Comment: So you should use callbacks, as another answer explained. Idea of callback is that you just starts request and not expects any results. Later, when results are ready, onResponse() should call some MainActivity method passing resulting array as argument and this method will actually use array. To implement this a good way is to declare interface with a single method, implement in in your activity and pass this interface to your movieArrayList() so that onResponse() could call it when time comes.